# How to fix unwanted deform when animating model

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode

I've just started learning how to animate and I'm trying to make this character walk. However, there are a lot of creases and bad deformations when I move the bones. I've tried weight painting, but I'm a complete beginner at it. This is the best I could achieve. How can I fix it so it deforms more naturally and smoothly?

[image]

[image]

here is the file [image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thankyou, I've added link to the file in my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the *Armature* modifier above the *Subdivision Surface*, also activate its *Preserve Volume* option.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

As for the remaning deformations, I think there's no magic trick, you need to correct the weight in *Weight Paint* mode.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Wow, it worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: There is still a problem around the arm pit of the character when its arm swings back. May I ask how to fix it? Do I need to fix the mesh or the weight paint?

Comment: for the remaning deformations, I think there's no magic trick, you need to correct the weight in *Weight Paint* mode, maybe change a bit the topology, maybe use segmented bendy bones, etc, see my edit

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I'll try it.